# SQL Prepared Parameter FireDac using "in"-clause

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am struggling using the in operator with FireDac.

I am using an oracle-database and cannot get a simple query working.

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Gender in (:Genders)';

FDQuery1.ParamByName('Genders').AsString:= 'M';
```

It works with one parameter but thats obviously not the purpose of the in operator.

Multiple values do not work however:

```
FDQuery1.ParamByName('Genders').AsString:= 'M, F';
FDQuery1.ParamByName('Genders').AsString := '''M'', ''W''';
```

Could it be that the in operator is not supported? 
And if so what would it be replaced with?

Comment: Use QuotedStr function

Comment: AFAIK, each parameter can handle a single value. You can try use multiple parameters: `... WHERE Gender IN (:p1,:p2);  FDQuery1.Parameters.ParamValues['p1;p2'] := VarArrayOf(['M','W']);`

Comment: @kobik oops accidently forgot it. That would work however one would have to adjust the query statement and not only the parameters.

Comment: Well, what you want can't be done with parameters b/c the `IN` parameters/expressions are comma separated and that is part of the SQL statement/syntax itself. Devart's UniQuery [for example](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=28913) has a concept of "macros" instead of parameters for such case, but I guess the command text is simply being dynamically populatted internally.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As FireDac also supports macros i'll have a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about MS Sql Server or a back-end with similar support for "IN", then you can't specify a series of values as a single parameter to an IN clause of a query.  However, a general (not FireDAC-specific) way to do this without using ad-hoc Sql (which carries the risk of Sql-Injection unless you are careful) is

- Use a series of Inserts (or `.InsertRecords` on a `TDataSet`) to insert the "IN" values in to a single-column temporary table.  The advantage of this is that you're not restricted by your parameterization to a specific number of values in the IN list.
- Then do a "Select * from MyTable where SomeColumn in (Select ColumnValue from #MyTempTable)

It's a bit of a performance compared with just specifying the IN list values in ad hoc Sql, of course, but not much as can be seen from the example below.  Using `TDFQuery`s, the creation of the INList table requires two steps, one to define it and the other to do a Select * from it.  Using `TAdoQuery`s instead, these two steps can be combined.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
  qInlist: TFDQuery;
  [etc]

 const
  scCreateINListTable =
  'if object_id(''tempdb.dbo.#countrycodes'', ''U'') is not null drop table #countrycodes'#13#10
   + 'create table #countrycodes (ACode char(2))';

   scOpenINList = 'select * from #countrycodes';

   scGetClients = 'select * from client where country in (select ACode from #countrycodes)';

procedure TForm1.GetClients;
begin
  qINList.SQL.Text := scCreateINListTable;
  qINList.ExecSQL;

  qINList.SQL.Text := scOpenINList;
  qINList.Open;

  qINList.InsertRecord(['US']);
  qINList.InsertRecord(['GB']);
  qINList.InsertRecord(['IT']);

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := scGetClients;
  FDQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetClients;
end;
```

Notice that this implementation doesn't require any parameterized or ad hoc Sql queries at all.

Answer (score 4):

I just found [this thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=172390&tstart=15) on the Embarcadero forums where User  Serge Girard    posted this solution:

use macro instead and perhaps in a little different way

```
SELECT * FROM `table` !mysel
and
Query.macrobyname('mysel').asraw:='WHERE Field in (1,2,3)';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE !mysel

no selection Query.MacroByName('mysel').asRaw:'1=1';
a selection Query.MacroByName('mysel').asRaw:'Field in (1,2,3)';
```

Comment: Anyway firedac is powerful, you can combine different style of macros:
'select * from table !mysel where &col_name = &value'

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use one parameter for a list, this works for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE charindex(Gender, :Genders) > 0
```

The value for the parameter should be any number of values separated by a character you know is not in the field (a pipe for example): |

If you pass 'M|F' it will bring back all M's and F's.

You can also do this in Oracle by using the instr function instead of charindex.

I hope this helps.